# VB6 Application Prints One Copy of Excel File in One Location but Two Copies in Another

Tags: excel, printing, vb6

We have a legacy VB6 application that prints work orders using an Excel template. Oddly, it prints one copy of the work order in one of our locations, but two copies in another. The reason I say "Oddly" is that this is the line that prints the file: `objExcelWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=True` What would make it ignore the `Copies:=2` in one physical location but obey it in another? The application lives on a server so both locations are using the same version. Could different versions of Excel cause this?

Comment: Are they using the same printer and printer driver? I have no real reason to suspect that there are drivers that ignore a Copies number beyond general distrust of printer drivers, though.

Comment: Different physical locations and different servers/printers, but I can log in to both servers. We still don't know why it prints 2 copies in one place but only one in the other.